# How to open a unique modal for each item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an IEnumerable of data that I'm looping through in my view, and each item has a "more information" button that pops a modal that should contain data specific to each item. Right now, no matter which item's button I click, I get the properties of the first item in the list.

My code after the button that opens the modal looks like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @item.Property1 // showing as the same for each item
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason is that, you are using similar id (which is "exampleModal") in each item of list for your modal. You should append something unique to id that defines your item. Change like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal-@item.Property1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">                                                                
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @item.Property1 // showing as the same for each item
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way, the modal will be uniquely identified.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried doing this and unfortunately the modal wouldn't open when the id is assigned this way. I double checked that the target and modal id matched, and it still wouldn't open for whatever reason. I ended up using a slide down div to display the content, and it works as intended. I know I could've probably gotten it to work with Ajax, but it seemed like overkill for data that was already rendered.